# stream_get_line dont read line as it arrives

Tags: php, curl, stream

I'm trying to read a streaming data using PHP.

So I would like to read and show every message posted from a server in real time.

I assume that $uri, $context from the code snipped are correctly defined.

When I use this code, the only result I got is when then lenght is reached. It seams that it doesnt stop on delimiter "\r" string.

```
DEFINE('TOKEN', "MY_TOKEN");

$opts = array(
  'http' => array(
    'method' => "GET",
    'header'=> "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode(TOKEN)));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
if (($fp = fopen($uri, "r", false, $context))) {
  while (!feof($fp)) {
    $contents = stream_get_line($fp, 1024, "\r");
    echo "text: " . $contents . "\n";
  }
fclose($fp);
```

When the lenght is reached, it show correctly all the new messages posted. with the string "text: " before every message.

How could I do to print one message by one ?

PS: I tried to use "\r", "\n", "\n\r" or "\r\n", nothing works :/.

I need some help there, thanks a lot.

Edit: adding the context

Comment: Your code looks good to me. Are you sure about your `$context` initialization (you assume it, but can't you post the code, just to put some more eyes on it)? And can you use a simple `fread` to display your first 1024 chars as hexadecimal to check what's your EOL char?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just edit the post by adding the context

Comment: Thanks, well, no, I do not see any mistake...

Comment: yeah the fread function give the same result with the same lenght limit :/

Comment: its seems that their is a stream buffer conflict or something because I have the "text: " before every line I received but all the text are printed when the limit is reached... that's weird.